# Java modulus operator

Tags: java, modulus

Use a modulus operator is something which all programmers must to know. I know it =).

In java we have :

```
int a = 100 , b = 50, c;
```

If we do :

```
c = a % b; // c = 0 because : 100 = 50*2 + 0 | D = d*q + r using simple maths
```

However I felt a little frustrated for not finding the Why of this operation :

```
c = b % a; // c = 50 ???? It seems not to have logic when a use D = d*q + r
```

Can someone could explain me why  50 % 100 is 50 ??? I can't understand very well.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Becuase you can multiply by 0:

```
c = 100*0 + 50;
```

It's the `+ 50` that is returned as modulo.

Answer (score 3):

Think of it this way:

`100 goes into 50 how many times?`

Zero times. So there must be `50` left over. Therefore the answer is `50`.